# How can I import my printer(s) into Google Cloud Print?

Tags: printing

I have Google Cloud Print, how do I import my Ubuntu printer into it so I can print to it from other devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install Google Cloud Print:

[image: Install via the software center]

Then you need to run it in a terminal, hit Ctrl-Alt-T and type in the following command:

```
cloudprint
```

It will then import your existing printers into Google Cloud Print. If you want to print to a Google Cloud Printer, see this question:

- [How can I easily set up a Google Cloud Print printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158874/how-can-i-easily-set-up-a-google-cloud-print-printer)