# How do I add my printer to Google Cloudprint?

Tags: server, printing, laptop, cloud, google

My printer is connected and shared by Ubuntu 14.04 server (old laptop).  I can use this printer with Windows laptop.

I wonder how can I add this printer to Google Cloudprint and make it accessible by Android phone.
In Windows I can do that via Google Chrome but no idea what to do with Ubuntu server.

Comment: Please use the search ;) See http://askubuntu.com/questions/158874/how-can-i-easily-set-up-a-google-cloud-print-printer

Comment: also interesting: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794179

Comment: @Rinzwind I already checked that link, it's adding google cloud printer to ubuntu. I'm trying to do vice-versa. I need this printer added to google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Google Cloud Print, you need to run it in a terminal by hitting Ctrl-Alt-T and typing the following command:

> cloudprint

Your existing printers will be then imported into Google Cloud Print.

You can also view this article that gives details about Google Cloud Printer on Ubuntu Server - https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/cups-cloud-print/