# My printer (Canon LBP6230dw), prints with too much density

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I'm having a difficult time getting my printer use a proper print density.

Perplexingly, it doesn't have any print quality settings apart from <kbd>Toner Save</kbd>.

With toner save enabled, the print comes out too light. However, if I disable it, the print is too dark - literally as dark as it can be.

- I have tried every setting. It seems to ignore most of them. (like gamma, saturation and brightness). It only responds to the <kbd>Toner Save</kbd> setting.
- The printer connected via network (wifi), with a driver used from Canon's website.
- In Windows everything is OK, and I can adjust the density to a desirable amount.

Isn't there some way that I can print with a density somewhere in the middle? Could this be a driver problem?

EDIT: I just noticed that when i try to print from Chrome in the preview, i see a color document instead of a greyscale. This is not a color printer. With my previous printer the preview was gray.

2n EDIT  **(10/10/2017)**: I tried to recalibrate the cups printer with:
    cups-calibrate
but i haven't managed the desired print.

3rd Edit **(12/10/2017)**: I have tried everything! I even did a manual edit of the etc/cups/ppd file. I manually added to that file all the driver's command line options from [Canon's Site](http://ug.oipsrv.net/USRMA-0587-zz-DR-enGB/contents/dlu-cmd-quality-reso.html) ! Even though i knew all options wasn't for my printer i played with them with no success. The most interesting option i added is [CNTonerDensity](http://ug.oipsrv.net/USRMA-0587-zz-DR-enGB/contents/dlu-cmd-quality-tnr_density.html). Still with no success.

Every time i get the same dark print like the example 3.

I have tried to get the brightness up with Gimp and managed well results. So i believe it's a brightness setting.

Just added a bounty.

4th Edit: **(24/10/2017)**: Just posted an answer with the workaround i use.

Things to try after that in the near future:

- Send an email for official support at Canon.
- Any suggestions from others witch not included here.

[image: Print tests]

2 is the desired density (windows). 3 is what gets printed with Ubuntu and <kbd>Toner Save: OFF</kbd>  and 1 is with <kbd>Toner Save: ON</kbd>

Comment: A big thank you, to the editors (@george @android-dev) witch made the question much more clear . The truth is that i was in desperate situation, after 3 and a half hours of trying (and almost 50 pages printed) in my office

Comment: I wonder which printer driver you use; Canon recommend their UFR from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100595001.html and I can supply a how-to if you wish

Comment: Yes i'm using the recommended. The one you are pointing to. Please supply a "how-to", just to confirm that i am doing it all as i should.

Comment: as in here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2373655, the file is linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken.tar.gz and if saved to a Downloads folder, the commands in sequence are `cd Downloads` then `tar -zxvf linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken.tar.gz` then `cd linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken` then `./install.sh`

Comment: Confirmed! I did them all correctly in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround Solution** (with cloud print)

The only solution i found is to install a google cloud printer. I did this following the question: [How can I easily set up a Google Cloud Print printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158874/how-can-i-easily-set-up-a-google-cloud-print-printer)

Since this printer is not "cloud ready" a windows PC has to be online so i can print with it's drivers.

Fortunately enough we have such a PC in the office (on air PC) so i installed cloud print on it following:

[Set up your printer with Google Cloud Print](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197)

I could have done the same thing through sharing a windows printer but with this solution i can print from my mobile (or any device) from anywhere (as long as the printer is powered).

The out come is exactly the same as if i am using the windows driver, so everything is fine for now.