# Libreoffice doesn't show google cloud printers

Tags: 18.04, printing, libreoffice, cloud, google

My google cloud printer is not listed in Libreoffice printing dialog window (and in other programs that have their own printing utility). Programs that use default Ubuntu printing utility (Evience, Thunderbird, Firefox etc.) can use google cloud printers despite that they are not listed in system printer settings. 
Do I need to add google cloud printers to system devices – printer settings (I assume that they are already there since I am able to use them from Evience or Thunderbird but for some reason they aren't visible)? 
There is a tool to manage CUPS/Google Cloud Print([How can I easily set up a Google Cloud Print printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158874/how-can-i-easily-set-up-a-google-cloud-print-printer)) but unfortunately there is no PPA for Ubuntu 18.04. 
I have also found this: 
https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cpdb-backend-gcp
But I had already messed up Libreoffice installing this. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: `cloudprint` should be available in the official repositories (it is for 16.04). No need for PPAs.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia True, but cloudprint "makes locally-defined CUPS printers available to a Google account" and I don't want that. I want to do it contrary – I want to make google account printers available locally. And partially it just works in Ubuntu 18.04 but not in libreoffice and other programs that have their own printing utility.

Comment: You can also compile from source the CUPS Cloud Print. I'll post a answer with the instructions.